# Django multiple view parameters and duplicated named urls

Tags: django, django-urls

I was just pondering if make two named urls the same produces any problems. I tried it and it works.
So for example, I have a view that is able to do paging:

```
def info(request, page_num = 1)
```

and I would like to call it both ways, as:

```
/info
/info/page/1
```

so I made urls like:

```
url(r'^info/$', 'views.info', name='info'),
url(r'^info/(?P<page_num>)\d+)/$', 'views.info', name='info'),
```

and it seems to work. Anything wrong with that, or should I name my second url differently, like **info_paginated** for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with that and as far as I know pretty standard practice. I know I do it, mostly when I'm using URL's that integrate with Javascript code and I don't have the parameter to use on page load.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine, but you might want to set `page_num = None`, then

```
if page_num is None:
    return redirect(reverse('info',{'page_num':1})
```

because a search engine sees yoursite.com/info and yoursite.com/info/1 and thinks they are duplicated content, if you redirect from one to another you will be fine.